# Remove n rows and iterate it n times in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 31 million of values in txt file. I need to remove values between 21600 to 61200, which I did through the code below and now I have to use this logic to remove for every 86400 values between above specified ones. This means remove values between 21600+86400 to 61200+86400, then remove 21600+86400+86400 to 61200+86400+86400 and so on applying same logic until the end of data. I tried many options, even using linked list, but I could not apply it to my large dataset. How shall it be done?

Visual example for values 1 to 24, remove values from 6 to `17:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 - - - - - - - - - - 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

then apply to the next set of rows who follow this structure as below (start 6+24=30 and stop 17+24=41):

```
25 26 27 28 29 30 - - - - - - - - - - 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
```

and so on until the end of data (remove between 30+24 and 41+24 for the next set).

I limited the code below for the first 250000 of values for simplicity.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample = np.arange(0, 259201, 1).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

df = df.drop(df.index[21601:61200])
```

Basically, I need to apply something like this below, but I am not sure how to do it for my case.

```
for day in reverse(range(366)):
    df.drop(df.index[21601+day*86400:61200+day*86400])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator to do so (`%` symbol in python and pandas).

Here is how your last piece of code can be re-written:

```py
df[~(df.index.to_series() % 86400).between(21601, 61200)]
```

I used `to_series()` because `between()` is not defined for Index objects.